# Added view does not appear on screen

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, prism-2

Why my "mainRegion.Activate(view);" doesn't display the view on screen?

It only works if I remove the default view that registered (RegisterViewWithRegion) in ModuleInit.cs though I don't put .Activate() after I added a View. But a problem occurs if I move to other module, and get back to module which default view has been removed, I get blank page.

Any clues? Thank you.
*) I prefer not to remove default view, but only with Activate(view) can show the View I want as explained in my reference.

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458899.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `Activate(view);` to `Remove(this);`

because my `view` is not inherited directly from `UserControl`.